# How to Debug Custom Devise Strategy in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a modified versions of Devise's example for an [LDAP authentication strategy](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Authenticate-via-LDAP). It's not working and I'm trying to do some Rails logging to figure it out, but the logging itself doesn't seem to be working either.

I started with `logger.debug 'Debug Info'`. Then tried `Rails.logger.debug 'Debug Info'`. And I even tried old-fashioned `puts 'Debug Info'`. None of these will show in the console.

This is the relevant part of my `config/initializers/ldap_authenticatable.rb`

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class LdapAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def authenticate!
        Rails.logger.debug '=== Starting LDAP Authentication ==='
        fail(:invalid_login) unless params[:user]
        ldap.auth find_dn, password
        Rails.logger.debug ldap.auth

        if ldap.bind
          Rails.logger.debug '=== LDAP Authorized! ==='
          user = User.find_or_create_by(email: email)
          success!(user)
        else
          Rails.logger.debug '=== LDAP Failed Auth! ==='
          fail(:invalid_login)
        end
      end
...
```

I've added the strategy to `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.default_strategies(scope: :user).unshift :ldap_authenticatable
  end
...
```

I modified my `User.rb` as needed

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :ldap_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable
...
```

And here is my Rails Log

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-11 18:38:16 -0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cv62THOWW4A/pGeflwrVlWSrABg0kY1UyJGBUoQz/B8daAs/9vMLhe1XTKmIbLWR3G6XXoRbvQ6Wis5GKVQiKA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"[REDACTED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "[REDACTED]"]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 20ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cv62THOWW4A/pGeflwrVlWSrABg0kY1UyJGBUoQz/B8daAs/9vMLhe1XTKmIbLWR3G6XXoRbvQ6Wis5GKVQiKA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"[REDACTED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (18.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 150ms (Views: 149.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So how do I print some values to the console? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `logger.debug "LDAP Authorized!"` is not showing up, then it's likely because your execution path is not hitting this section of code.  To confirm your code is executing, try raising an exception along parts of its path.

Raising an exception is easier for debugging controllers than trying to sift through Rails logs, and helps immediately confirm whether certain parts of your code are even being executed.  To add an exception, try adding a line of code such as `raise ldap.inspect` to parts of your controller flow to see if that section of code is running.

When debugging, calling `.inspect` on any instance variables within this code path will also be helpful, giving you information on the temporary state of objects that may give you insight into why things aren't working.

Comment: You're right, I added an exception at the top of my authenticate method and sure enough it's not being reached.

Comment: @brownmike Did you ever figure out why the code wasn't being reached?